# What is similar to nextpvr

Tags: software-recommendation, tv, tv-tuner

My dad wants to use Linux. I'll put him on a lightweight version because he wants to use it as Minecraft sever. He uses a PVR he got where he plugs his local antenna to his computer by using WinTV HVR and use a program called NextPVR he's able to record, look at a TV Guide, and record new episodes. Is there a Linux program that does the same thing or can I use NextPVR on wine?

Answer (score 2):

This list is by no means exhaustive. I would adivse you to try 2 or 3 of the open source options to understand which suits best your needs.

## [MythTV](https://www.mythtv.org/)

This is the most reputable option for Linux, has been around since 2002 - initially as an alternative to TiVo - and comes with plenty of features. It is released under a GPL licence and available from the Software Centre; detailed install and configuration instructions are available at the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MythTV/Install/Server/Backend).

[image]

## [**Kodi**](http://kodi.tv/)

This is another old guard programme that retains some popularity. Beyond live TV and personal recording, it also provides plug-ins to access streaming services such as YouTube, Amazon Prime or Spotify. Kodi is released under a GPL licence and available from a third party PPA; install instructions are available at the [Kodi wiki](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux).

[image]

**Note**: Since you are installing a new system, you might wish to take a look at [**Kodibuntu**](http://kodi.wiki/view/Kodibuntu). This is an interesting option if you are not intending to do much else with this system.

## [**SageTV**](http://www.sagetv.com/)

A media centre that existed as a commercial product for about a decade. In 2011 it was acquired by Google, whom opened the code this year under an Apache licence. It counts PVR among its features, but it has not been developed that much since Google bought it. I could not find install instructions for recent releases.

## [**tvtime**](http://tvtime.sourceforge.net/)

This is a less popular TV programme with recording capabilities. The latest release is from 2005 but it seems to still have a relevant number of users.

[image]

## [**JRiver**](http://www.jriver.com/)

This is a popular proprietary multimedia programme that is almost 20 years old. Among other things, it supports TV recording and keeps a TV station library. It still has a large community around it, an interesting option among the commercial software.

--

Finally, it might be a good idea to write a message to the NextPVR folk asking them for a Linux version, explaining that you will quit using their software if they do not do so.

Comment: Kodi shouldn't be on the list.  It's not a DVR itself, although it can attach to DVRs.  http://kodi.wiki/view/PVR_backend.